# Shortcut to toggle EU Volume Limit

Tags: ios, sound-volume, shortcuts-app

With the Shortcuts app you can create an icon on your home screen that automates a task.  There seem to be plenty of options.  I'm looking for a way to toggle the `Settings > Music > EU volume limit` switch.  This would allow me to toggle it `on` for music but `off` for podcasts.

Which part of Shortcuts can toggle the volume limit?

Comment: Which iOS version are you on ? Rumour has it that iOS13 brought in some new shortcuts too.

Comment: @ankii using the latest iOS. I can't find a simple shortcut, but was hoping one of the scripting options might be able to do this.

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no such feature, however, you could use the ‘podcasts’ app to listen to your podcasts.

Comment: I don't think OP asked for where to listen podcasts. They are already doing it. What is required is, shortcut to toggle a setting, that is different for music and podcast.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how this answer helps the OP to use different volume levels/limits?